# When is the image of a GNS representation WOT-dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a state $\rho$ on $A$, let $\pi_\rho$ be the corresponding GNS representation on the Hilbert space $H_\rho$. I would like know when the image of $\pi_\rho$ is WOT-dense in $B(H_\rho)$.

> Is it sufficient to assume that $\rho$ is a pure state?

Comment: I suggest you write and accept your answer, so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah yes, this is indeed true. $\pi_\rho$ is irreducible if and only if $\rho$ is pure. And a representation is irreducible if and only if its range is SOT-dense, which by the Bicommutant theorem is equivalent to WOT-density.